# How to implement automatic steering of Elasticsearch shard size?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a stream of incoming data (logs) that are stored in Elasticsearch. I need to implement a functionality that would check continuously the size of a shard and, when it reaches a certain point (e.g. 30GB), it would start storing data in a new shard.

I am new to Elasticsearch and I could not find any information regarding how to do that. Do I need to create a new index for each shard in this case?

I will be grateful for any info or links. I am using Elasticsearch 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Rollover Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-rollover-index.html), which should suit your need.

It basically goes like this. You need to have an alias pointing to a single index, below we're creating an index `myindex-000001` with an alias `myalias`

```
PUT /myindex-000001 
{
  "aliases": {
    "myalias": {}
  }
}
```

Then you need to create a rollover condition, like this:

```
POST /myalias/_rollover 
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_size":  "30gb"
  }
}
```

Whenever the index pointed to by `myalias` reaches 30gb in size, a new index called `myindex-000002` will be created and the alias will switch to it. So as far as your client application is concerned you can always send your data to `myalias` and ES does the rest.

Comment: ok so this means a new index will be created each time? is there a way to apply the condition to shards and not indices? that would allow more shards to be stored within an index.

Comment: No, you cannot put conditions on shards, and that wouldn't really make sense since a shard can grow in size during merge operations without necessarily containing more documents.